# Extract before and after a pattern and populate additional columns in an existing dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe in r with three columns and millions of rows. What I want to do is to split the middle column values at a pattern `_GM_` and split the string into two separately populated columns. e.g. Column name which is to be split `child_name` having value as string `DE_E_PP_PV_ESE_GM_BB_Bern_150` . The final output should be an existing dataframe with additional two columns having values before and after the split. e.g. first additional column name should be `child_category` with the value`DE_E_PP_PV_ESE` and second additional column `Connection` with the value `BB_Bern_150`. I have tried many ways but I failed to construct a proper `gregexpr` to split it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tidyr package as follow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate(child_name, c("child_category", "Connection"), "_GM_", remove = F) ## Add remove = F to sḱeep 'old' column
```

Comment: @Mark where did I forget a backet? I just tested my code and it works :)

Comment: ahah, sorry I did not know you could edit other people's post, Thank you then :)

Comment: I used it it went well but original column doesn't exist anymore, so is it possible to have original child_name in the dataframe with two new populated columns?

Comment: I have edited my original post by adding ```remove = F```, I did not know that you wanted to keep the original column

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [`separate_wider_delim()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  child_name = "DE_E_PP_PV_ESE_GM_BB_Bern_150")

df |> separate_wider_delim(child_name, names = c("child_category", "Connection"), delim = "_GM_")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  child_category Connection 
  <chr>          <chr>      
1 DE_E_PP_PV_ESE BB_Bern_150
```